# how to clone hyperlinks

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, pagination, clone

How to clone/copy link where edits/changes in one hyperlink affect the other? Let me explain this.

I have used pagination function in my WordPress site  (used Wp-pagenavi plugin) and it's working fine. How, I wish to call the same in header. I understand this will not work since this function

`if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) )
wp_pagenavi();
else
get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );` needs

`( have_posts() ) : the_post();` function inside the **index.php**.

Now, I wish the same function in another place where changes in pagination links affect those in header.php or anywhere else something like **copy link* in MS Excel where a change in one cell automatically affect there cell where that cell is copied. Hope my question makes sense.

**Updated:**

okay let me explain further.

Pagination in the page: 1,2,**3**,4,5.....10 (working fine here. The code is in index.php file).

Now wish to place the same workable pagination in header. php file where it should function the way it's doing in the page. See he screenshot for better understanding https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSAGf . png (*SF does not allow me to attach screenshot. Please remove spaces from the appropriate areas*)

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't makes sense to me at least

Comment: I just updated my post. Can you please it once again. I have attached one image there too.